# Clickonce error in C:\Windows\System32\dfshim.dll missing entry "shopenverbapplication"

Tags: c#, clickonce, rundll32

I am having issues with some of our QA users who run in a very restricted VDI. Cyber have given them access to install certain things and even to rundll32.exe for some previous issue but now when we try and use Clickonce installers (which essentially just copy and paste files) we are getting this error.

```
Error in C:\Windows\System32\dfshim.dll missing entry "ShOpenVerbApplication"
```

There doesn't seem to be another way to launch Clickonce installers, does anyone know of any? I have a workaround that copies the files and removes the .deploy extension but it's not great.